# address reuse error when using fork() + execlp with boost::asio in Linux

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, fork, boost-asio

I have a program which listens on a TCP port for particular string and launches an application using `execlp` call. I am doing a `fork()` to launch a child process before this `execlp` call. After this launch parent process again starts listening on the same port. I am closing the socket in child process.

I have written a wrapper over `boost::asio::tcp_socket` where I am setting the `addr_reuse` option to `true` before binding the socket.

Now my problem is in Linux I get an Address reuse error after a few launches of the application. In my program it continuously tries to accept connections (or more precisely tries to schedule an accept to `boost::asio::io_service`) until bind and then accept succeed. So I receive the error in this loop.

Strangely, if I close (or kill) the launched executable this error stops coming, which means `bind` succeeds. I am sure that in the launched application the same port is not being used anywhere.
I am using asynchronous socket operations. Any idea why I am getting this error?

Here is how I am accepting on the socket: (I also call reset on the `boost::asio::tcp_socket(_tcpSocket)` shared pointer before starting a new accept.)

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endPoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
_acceptor.reset ( new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor( *_ioService.get() ) );
_acceptor->open( endPoint.protocol() );
_acceptor->set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));

boost::system::error_code ec;
_acceptor->bind(endPoint, ec);
if ( ec.value() != boost::system::errc::success )
{
    ec.clear();
    _acceptor->close(ec);
    close();
    return false;
}

ec.clear();
_acceptor->listen(boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections, ec);
if ( ec.value() != boost::system::errc::success )
{
    return false;
}
_acceptor->async_accept(*_tcpSocket,
                        boost::bind(&TCPSocket::_handleAsyncAccept,
                                    this,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error) );
```

Here is how I am forking:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
switch (pid)
{
    case 0:
    {
        /// close all sockets for child process. as it might cause addr reuse error in parent process
        _asyncNO->closeAll();
        std::string binary = "<binaryName>";
        std::string path = "<binaryPath>";
        if ( execlp( path.c_str(), binary.c_str(), controllerIP.c_str(), (char *)0 ) == -1 )
        {
            LOG_ERROR("System call failed !!")
        }
    }
    break;

    default:
}
```

I have removed logging for simplicity.

Comment: Boost.Asio needs to be notified of the `fork()`; otherwise, undefined behavior may occur.  It may be worth implementing the `fork()` notifications noted in the [docuemtnation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/fork.html), and seeing if this resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @TannerSansbury said in the comments, this is likely because Boost.Asio needs to be notified of `fork()`:

[Newer version of the documentation on forking with Boost.Asio.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/fork.html)

Relevant section reproduced here:

> Boost.Asio supports programs that utilise the `fork()` system call. Provided the program calls `io_service.notify_fork()` at the appropriate times, Boost.Asio will recreate any internal file descriptors (such as the "self-pipe trick" descriptor used for waking up a reactor). The notification is usually performed as follows:

```cpp
io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_prepare);
if (fork() == 0)
{
  io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_child);
  // ...
}
else
{
  io_service_.notify_fork(boost::asio::io_service::fork_parent);
  // ...
}
```

> User-defined services can also be made fork-aware by overriding the `io_service::service::fork_service()` virtual function.
>
> Note that any file descriptors accessible via Boost.Asio's public API (e.g. the descriptors underlying `basic_socket<>`, `posix::stream_descriptor`, etc.) are not altered during a fork. It is the program's responsibility to manage these as required.